# Why does my forget() method not remove object from collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a collection of "Tickets", using the `random` collection utility method I select one from the list. The "Tickets" collection should now remove (or forget) that randomly selected ticket so I can further process that collection. Using the `forget` method doesn't appear to do what is described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forget) or (more likely I'm missing something).

Can someone spot whats wrong in my code?

```
$tickets = Tickets::all();
$total_winners = 5;
$selected_tickets = $tickets->random($total_winners);
$jackpot_winner = $selected_tickets->random();
$selected_tickets->forget($jackpot_winner->id); // this line should remove the $jackpot_winner
```

When I print the contents of `$selected_tickets` on lines 3 and lines 5, they have the exact same items, including the `$jackpot_winner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget function uses the collection key not the id from the model. To achieve what you want you may use this method:

```
$selected_tickets = $selected_tickets->except($jackpot_winner->id);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-except